# Lambda Calculus list append

Tags: lambda, calculus

I am trying to append a single number to a list in lambda calculus and i am struggling to find any worked examples using church numerals, could someone please point me in the direction of some list appending examples in lambda calculus

Answer (score 0):

For modeling algebraic data types in the lambda calculus I would recommend scott encoding. Kwang has a nice blog post on it https://kseo.github.io/posts/2016-12-13-scott-encoding.html.

Here's some haskell that corrisponds to your use case.

```hs
-- model as adt in haskell
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

-- apply scott encoding
data ListS a r = ListS (forall r. r -> (a -> ListS -> r) -> r)

-- make constructors

nil :: ListS a
nil = ListS (\n c -> n)

cons :: a -> ListS a -> ListS a
cons x xs = ListS (\n c -> c x xs)
```

or in pure lambda calculus

```
nil = \n c -> n
cons = \x xs n c -> c x xs
```